# Существуют ли такие значения x и y

Tags: математика

Существуют ли такие x и y при которых  √(x^2 + y) = целое число и √(y^2 + x) = целое число.

Comment: Интересуют целые x и y? Тривиальные корни (0, 1) не интересуют?

Comment: `x = 0`, `y = 0` или `x = 1`, `y = 0` или `x = 1`, `y = -1`

Comment: @Fat-Zer, разве (1; -1) не даёт корень из двух во втором уравнении?

Comment: @vp_arth Тривиальные - это (0,n^2), а не только (0,1)... Еще одно нетривиальное решение - (-1,-1) :)

Comment: Вот бы найти что-нибудь с `|x|>=|y|>1`, не удивлюсь, что там корней нет =)

Comment: @vp_arth, да, опечатка... (-1,-1) конечно...

Comment: В общем, кроме `-1,-1`,  `0, k**2` корней вроде и нет =)

Comment: Скорее всего, в оригинальной задаче речь шла о натуральных x и y, тогда решений нет)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Будем разбирать случаи:

---

1. `x > 0`, `y > 0`

`sqrt(x^2 + y) > sqrt(x^2)` <=>
`sqrt(x^2 + y) > x` <=> (корень целое число)

`sqrt(x^2 + y) >= x + 1` <=>
`x^2 + y >= (x + 1)^2` <=>
`x^2 + y >= x^2 + 2x + 1` <=>

`y >= 2x + 1` <=>
`-2x + y >= 1` <=>
`2x - y <= -1`

Аналогично выводим `2y - x <= -1`.

Складываем оба неравенства: `y + x <= -2`.

Противоречие.

---

2. `x < 0`, `y < 0`

`sqrt(x^2 + y) < sqrt(x^2)` <=>
`sqrt(x^2 + y) < -x` <=> (корень целое число)

`sqrt(x^2 + y) <= -x - 1` <=> `x^2 + y <= (-x - 1)^2` <=>
`x^2 + y <= x^2 + 2x + 1` <=>

`y <= 2x + 1` <=> `-2x + y <= 1` <=> `2x - y >= -1`

Аналогично выводим `2y - x >= -1`.

Складываем оба неравенства: `y + x >= -2`.

Единственное решение `x = y = -1`.

---

3. `x < 0`, `y > 0`

`sqrt(x^2 + y) > sqrt(x^2)` <=>
`sqrt(x^2 + y) > -x` <=> (корень целое число)

`sqrt(x^2 + y) >= -x + 1` <=> `x^2 + y >= (-x + 1)^2` <=>
`x^2 + y >= x^2 - 2x + 1` <=>

`y >= -2x + 1` <=> `2x + y >= 1`

`sqrt(y^2 + x) < sqrt(y^2)` <=>
`sqrt(y^2 + x) < y` <=> (корень целое число)

`sqrt(y^2 + x) <= y - 1` <=> `y^2 + x <= (y - 1)^2` <=>
`y^2 + x <= y^2 - 2y + 1` <=>

`x <= -2y + 1` <=> `2y + x <= 1` <=> `-2y - x >= -1`

Складываем оба неравенства: `x - y >= 0`.

Противоречие.

Остальные случаи оставляю в качестве упражнения.

Answer (score -1):

Введем ограничения `x^2 + y >= 0` и `y^2 + x >= 0`
Теперь можем смело возвести в квадрат, получить `x^2 + y = y^2 + x`

То есть `x^2 - y^2 = x - y`
`(x - y) * (x + y) = (x - y)`.

То есть либо `x = y`, либо `(x + y) = 1`, корни x и y в этом случае должны удовлетворять ограничениям выше.

Comment: а откуда мысль, что выражения должны быть равны? В вопросе указано, что результаты корня - целые числа, а не что они равны между собой

Comment: Да, признаю, упустил этот момент про целое число. Думаю автор докрутит.

Comment: Каким образом он докрутит? :-)

Comment: Либо `x=y`, либо `x!=y`. Дальше автор докрутит

Comment: Даже допустив, что равенство выражений, как получилось у Egettl, полученный им результат не дает способа найти решения, только показывает связь между корнями исходных уравнений. Например, пары (1, 1) и (3, -2) удовлетворяют, соответственно, первому и второму полученным ограничениям, но не являются решениями исходной задачи.